# The issue with at least in probability

Tags: probability

If I am trying to calculate the probability that a student will solve at least 4 problems out of 10, when they have prepared for 7 of them, is that the same as solving for probability of not solving 4 problems? How should I think about this whole idea of at least. I am trying to do it as a complement, but it is a bit tricky to wrap my head around them.

Comment: The complement of solving at least $4$ problems is solving $\leq3$ problems.

Comment: What does "prepared for a question" imply about the probability of a student to solve it?

Comment: as in can complete it 100% of the time. so memorized it.

Answer (score 1):

At least means more than or equal to. The probability of solving at least 4 problems = the probability of solving 4 problems + the probability of solving 5 problems + ... up to 10 problems